# Compilation error g++

Tags: c++

I tried to compile this example from https://github.com/augcampos/asterisk-cpp/wiki/Examples but I get this error:

```
root@debian:~# g++ TesteCpp.cpp -o tt -lasteriskcpp
TesteCpp.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
TesteCpp.cpp:13:39: error: invalid conversion from ‘void (*)(asteriskcpp::ManagerEvent*)’ to ‘asteriskcpp::onManagerEventCallback_t {aka void (*)(const asteriskcpp::ManagerEvent&)}’ [-fpermissive]
In file included from TesteCpp.cpp:4:0:
/usr/local/include/asteriskcpp/manager/ManagerConnection.h:49:14: error:   initializing argument 1 of ‘void asteriskcpp::ManagerConnection::addEventCallback(asteriskcpp::onManagerEventCallback_t)’ [-fpermissive]
```

How to fix it?

TesteCpp.cpp:

```
//TesteCpp.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "asteriskcpp/utils/LogHandler.h"
#include "asteriskcpp/manager/ManagerConnection.h"

using namespace asteriskcpp;
void eventCallback(ManagerEvent* me) {
    std::cout << std::endl << "TEST:EVENT" << me->toLog() << std::endl;
} 

int main() {
    ManagerConnection mc;
    mc.addEventCallback(&eventCallback); // add event listener
    if (mc.connect("192.168.1.6")) {
        if (mc.login("admin", "zzz")) {
            mc.logoff();
        }
    }
    mc.disconnect();
    return (0);
 }
```

Comment: could you provide more code please? At least TesteCpp.cpp (around line 13)?

Comment: Did you read the error message? You're passing one type of function pointer where a different type is expected.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on a *quick* scan of the code

```
void eventCallback(ManagerEvent* me) {
    std::cout << std::endl << "TEST:EVENT" << me->toLog() << std::endl;
}
```

should be

```
void eventCallback(const ManagerEvent& me) {
    std::cout << std::endl << "TEST:EVENT" << me.toLog() << std::endl;
}
```